# Unable to load fixture for model with PK on a OneToOneField

Tags: django

Django fails to set parent's ID when loading fixture for a model with OneToOneField set as primary key.
models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Parent(models.Model):
    base_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class Child(Parent):
    base = models.OneToOneField(Parent,
                                parent_link=True,
                                primary_key=True,
                                related_name="child")
```

fixture:

```
[
{
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "fiddle.parent", 
    "fields": {}
},
{
    "pk": 2, 
    "model": "fiddle.parent", 
    "fields": {}
},
{
    "pk": 3, 
    "model": "fiddle.parent", 
    "fields": {}
},
{
    "pk": 1, 
    "model": "fiddle.child", 
    "fields": {}
},
{
    "pk": 2, 
    "model": "fiddle.child", 
    "fields": {}
},
{
    "pk": 3, 
    "model": "fiddle.child", 
    "fields": {}
}
]
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 55, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 84, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 140, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 164, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1511, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 898, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/tmp/pkTest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/tmp/pkTest/testPK/./db.json': Could not load fiddle.Child(pk=None): null value in column "base_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null).
```

I use PostgreSQL as database. Any ideas how to solve this? Is this a django bug? Couldn't find noone who has had a similar problem :(

Comment: And what does your fixture look like?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add fixture. Fixed :)

Comment: Hmm. Just tried it on a blank project and it worked perfectly for me on Django 1.6.2. Had to modify the model names to `fiddle.Parent` and `fiddle.Child`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Maybe it's something else in your project that's causing the problem?

Comment: This example already is from an empty project. Changed fieldname base in the child to _base and it worked